# AS3 Regex test for URL

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I want to check if a string contains a URL.

```
var string:String = "Arbitrary amount of random text before and after.<br/><br/>http://www.somdomain.co.uk<br/><br/>Tel: 0123 456 789<br/>";

var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#])?");

ExternalInterface.call('console.log',pattern.test(string));
```

This outputs false to my console, whereas when I feed the regex and string into http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, the url is found.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just escaped a couple extra `/` and it started working. Also, I generally like to use the regex literal notation to create regexes as it gives you better syntax highlighting than converting a string to a regex in the `new Regex()`:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&\/~\+#])?/;
```

Comment: This is the first time I have used RegExp in AS3. This worked brilliantly, thanks :)